# How can I continuously run a bash script checking if a value has changed?

Tags: bash

I have a PHP script `getAnalytics.php` that when called, returns a specific integer value. I want to be able to call `getAnalytics.php` in a bash script that runs continuously checking the PHP script every 30 seconds to see if the value returned has changed.

How would I go about doing this? Or would you recommend a different method?

Comment: Why not edit the php script to do a loop for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no better indication (watching some log file e.g.) to get notification of a possible change just endlessly loop in bash:

```
res=
while [ 1 ] ; do
   old_result=$res
   res=$(/path/to/getAnalytics.php)
   echo "result: $res"
   if [ "$old_result" != "$res" ]; then
     echo "result has changed"
   fi
   sleep 30
done
```

You will need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit. If you want to exit on a particular value (e.g. 42) printed by the script set `res` to some dummy value at the beginning and then test for `[ "$res" != "42" ]`

Comment: I keep getting `/myapp/test.php: line 1: 345234: command not found result,`

Comment: @TreyCopeland what happens when you run `/myapp/test.php` from the commandline? Does that file have a shebang line? If not it is not an executable script and you have to call it with `php /myapp/test.php`.

Comment: Why `while [ 1 ] ;` rather than `while :;` or `while true;` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring Looks better after 30 years of usage?

Comment: I'll pay that; the `:` is easy to overlook. `true` is easier to see, but it seems a bit wasteful to me to load a do-nothing command like that from disk.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't think that speed is an issue if the OP can use PHP. And this way, where to put the exit loop with testing on `$res` requires less explaining.

Answer (score 0):

If you could relax your requirements to a minute between runs, you can easily do this via a cron entry.  The advantage of this process is that a program does not simply sit around (and possibly die) causing you to miss some data or window.  Also no special steps would be required to start it up between reboots.